# How to edit MP3 tags in WIndows media player to have proper track listing

Tags: audio, mp3, windows-media-player

So I recently got an album that I noticed when I play it on Windows Media Player or any other location (such as my car) the track listing is messed up and not playing in the order that it is supposed to as according to the album track listing. I've tried editing the metadata tags by going into *right click on file* --> *properties* -- > *details* tab. Then editing the Media #, but it is to no avail. Anything else I could do to set it up properly?

Comment: In WMP, in *Alt > Play* menu, is Shuffle checked? And are you playing the files from within WMP's library?

Comment: No. What I usually do is have each album separated by folder. So I would usually open up WMP and drag the folder over to the WMP with the list option activated. Then I would have the listing of the tracks while they play. Alternatively if I have the album on a USB and I plag it in the car the same messed up track listing occurs. It appears to read the songs as 1, 10, 11, 12,...,2, 3, 4, 5......etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be a victim of
[Numerical Sorting](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/91417-enable-disable-numerical-sorting-file-explorer-windows-10-a.html).

I guess that the titles in the list look like:

```
1 song1
2 song2
...
10 song10
etc.
```

They are not listed correctly in WMP or the car player,
which is only natural - this is after all a pure Windows 10 Explorer feature,
so the list is only listed correctly in Explorer.

You would need to rename the titles so they look like:

```
01 song1
02 song2
...
10 song10
etc.
```

Comment: So I tried adding 0's in front of the songs in the "#" cell. The cell located in the details tab. Which tag do the media devices read to determine ordering?

Comment: Depending on the format of your album, but to rename it might be enough to right-click on the title and select Edit, or click it and press F2.

Comment: Yes this ended up working. The alternative was messing with the REG files, which I don't want to do...